# cpuinfo to decide processor affinity

Tags: c, linux, cpu-cache

I've tried to decide processor affinity rule for my applications  according to /proc/cpuinfo  , My redhat Linux showes

```
processor   : 0   to  47  , means server has 48 processor unit

physical id : 0   to  3   , means server has 4 cpu sockets 

cpu cores   : 6  , means  each socket has 6 cores 

siblings    :  12 , means each core has 2  hyperthreads
```

So totally , this server has 4 * 6 * 2 = 48 processor units , am I correct so far ?

What I like to do is to use sched_setaffinity function , first I like to know is 
the hyperthreads in the same core , for example ...

```
processor 0  : physical id:0,core id: 0  ...
processor 24 : physical id:0,core id: 0  ...
```

If in my application , I use CPU_SET(0, &mask)  in thread1 , CPU_SET(24, &mask)
in thread2  , then I might can say that thread1 and thread2 will share the same L1 cache,
and of course share the same L2 cache , too ...am I correct in this guess ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only guarantee fully shared caches if your threads are being scheduled on the same core (i.e. different hyperthreads) in which case your approach is correct.

But keep in mind that scheduling two tasks on the same core will not necessarily make them run faster then if you schedule them on different cores. L3 which is commonly shared among all cores is very fast.

You need to check how caches are shared among your processors. Most Intel processors share L2 among 2-4 cores and L3 among all cores while most AMD models only share L3.